# I am trying to count the number of elements currently in a linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

```
int OOLList::getListSize() {
    int count = 0;
    OOLNode* iterator = NULL;

    // If the stack is empty return 0
    if (this->start != NULL) {
        count = 0;
    }

    // If the Stack isn't empty
    else {
        while (iterator->next != NULL) {
            iterator = iterator->next;
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

I am getting an error that says "Dereferencing NULL pointer 'iterator'".  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could step through with your debugger, set a breakpoint for the start of this function, step through, and see the issue. `this` is unlikely to be `NULL`, so I assume your issue is with `iterator`. Therefore, `this->start == NULL`, which triggers the `else` block, which attempts to dereference `iterator`, which you explicitly set to `NULL` above.

Comment: I think  `(this->start != NULL)` will be true  if your stack has elements

Comment: For an error like this (and since the error message was kind enough to tell you the name of the variable), one of the first things I would check is whether or not there is a line that assigns (or could assign) a non-null value to `iterator`. Set a breakpoint on that line and see if it is hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you initialize `iterator` to NULL and don't set it to anything else before accessing `iterator->next`.

Presumably `start` is the first node in your list.  When `start` is not NULL (the list is not empty), you return 0. And when `start` is NULL (the list is empty), you try to iterate. Your logic is backwards.

Try this instead:

```cpp
int OOLList::getListSize() {
    int count = 0;
    OOLNode* iterator = this->start;
    while (iterator != NULL) {
        ++count;
        iterator = iterator->next;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set iterator to NULL in your function and you never set it to anything else, then you dereference the pointer in your while condition.

You should assign the iterator to somehing, like itetator = start instead of NULL

Answer (score -1):

I think you are doing it wrong. You have to count number of element in stack. Do it like this:

```
int OOLList::getListSize() {
    int count = 0;
    OOLNode* iterator = NULL;
    iterator = start; // hope start is also OOLNode*
    // If the stack is empty return 0
    if (iterator== NULL) {
        count = 0;
    }

    // If the Stack isn't empty
    else {
        while (iterator->next != NULL) {
            iterator = iterator->next;
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: For non-empty lists you return one less than the size. Presumably, a 1-element list would have `start` point to a node whose `next` pointer is null. Walk through your code; it returns `0` in this case.